# Spring Boot Actuator Endpoint "Not Found" for Wildfly Deployment since version 2.4.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, wildfly, spring-boot-actuator

Since Spring Boot Release 2.4.0 the actuator endpoints don't work for me anymore if I choose to deploy the application as a WAR-file on Wildfly.

My Pom looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To run under Wildfly 23.y.z -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

additionally I have the `jboss-web.xml` file under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` with the content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/helloworld/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The endpoint `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/actuator/health` for example is reachable if i downgrade the Spring Boot version to 2.3.12.RELEASE but returns a 404 code for Spring Boot 2.4.X and 2.5.X. If I run the application as a normal JAR-file with the embedded Tomcat the actuator endpoint is exposed successfully (under `http://localhost:8080/actuator/health`).

My Setup:

```
Wildfly: 23.0.2.Final
Java: AdoptOpenJDK - 11.0.10+9
```

Comment: It sounds like you application may have failed to deploy. If that's the case, Wildfly's logs should contain some information about the error.

Comment: The deployment does not fail. But you brought me on the right track nevertheless. I implemented a basic Restcontroller to check if the deployment works and it was also not accessible. Changing the `<context-root>` from `/helloworld/` to `helloworld` solved my problem!